# MQTT sobre 802.15.4 en C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, mqtt

Estoy conectando un módulo basado en 802.15.4 a la Raspberry a través de la UART para poder comunicarlo con su pareja en Ubuntu o en otra raspberry también conectado a través de la UART.

La cuestión es que quiero mandar los mensajes de un módulo a otro con MQTT en C. ¿Cómo habría que hacer para que esos mensajes se dirigiesen a la UART y el módulo los retransmitiese a su homólogo?
Cuando se emplea una librería, se define la dirección del broker como ADDRESS y la dirección IP con el puerto, ¿habría que configurar el PANID que tengo adjudicado a los módulos ahí?
He estado mirando librerías tanto de MQTT como de MQTT-SN, pero ningún ejemplo de lo que busco.

La solución que estoy intentando implementar ahora es hacer un puente en el broker de mosquitto para que redireccione directamente a la UART, ¿se puede hacer? Y en caso de que sí, ¿como sería la configuración?

Edito:
Busco algo como este script https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90002258/tasks/t_use_mqtt.htm pero para realizar en c. He conseguido que con el ejemplo de python me envíe los datos, así que he intentado desarrollar el siguiente código en c, obteniendo como resultado... que me escribe solo 0x10 y 0x11... ¿Qué diferencias exiten entre la función de setup y el hilo SockReaderThread que está en el código en Python y el de c para que no obtenga lo mismos resultados?

```
#include "project.h"
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int fd,baudrate=9600,sock=0,new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

int setup(){
    
    int opt=1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(serv_addr);
    if(wiringPiSetup() <0) return 1;
    if((fd=serialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate))<0) return 1;
    printf("Serial communication opened \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1881);
    
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(sock, 1) <0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("1\n");
    if ((new_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    printf("1\n");
    return 0;
}


PI_THREAD(socketRead){
    

    int valread;
    char buffer[4096] = {0}; 

    
    //Nos mantenemos a la escucha
    for(;;){
        valread = recv( new_socket, buffer, 1024,0);
        //valread = read(new_socket,buffer,4096);
        if ( valread == -1 ) {
            printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
            return 0 ;
        }   
        if ( strlen(buffer) !=0 ){      
        printf("buffer %s\n",buffer);
        write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    }
    } 
    
}


int main(){
    
    setup();
    /* Thread creation */
    piThreadCreate (socketRead);
    for(;;){}
    
    return 0;
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: La manera más sencilla de hacerlo es montar una conexión **ppp** a través del puerto UART. Mira esta página: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html

Comment: Uff se me espaca un poco de mis conocimientos eso, a ver si me entero. Básicamente es ejecutar en la consola la instrucción " pppd -detach crtscts lock proxyarp <IP local>: <IP remota> / dev / ttyS3 38400 &" donde en ip local pongo la ip de mi raspberry y en ip remota de ubuntu  y sustituyo ttyS· por el puerto que esté utilizando y 38400 por los baudios. Pero cómo sabe en qué puerto lo estoy enviando, lo tengo que indicar dentro de las IP?

Comment: Los parámetros `<local IP>` y `<remote IP>` deberían ser dos IPs diferentes a las que tienes en tu red local y son las IPs entre las que "se verán" ambos equipos. Es decir, desde la primera RPI haces ping a `<remote IP>` y te contestará el otro extremo y viceversa. De modo que cuando quieras conectarte al MQTT del otro extremo deberás usar `<remote IP>` como IP del servidor. PD: Recuerda que en el otro extremo deberás intercambiar las IPs ya que la IP remota ahora será la local y la local ahora es la que antes era la remota.

Comment: Vale, eso lo entiendo. Pero, en la RPI estoy enviando los mensajes a localhost:1883 como si fuese el broker, esto quiere decir, que al hacer el ppp, ¿donde ponga local IP tengo que configurarlo también como localhost:1883 (indicando el puerto) y del mismo modo en la remota? Gracias!

Comment: Cuando conectas a `localhost:1883` estás conectando al puerto `1883` del equipo local (`127.0.0.1` o `localhost`). Si quieres que se conecte al equipo remoto deberás usar `<remote IP>:1883`.

Comment: El problema de que si indico el remoto, no lo va a encontrar. Es decir, lo que estoy intentando es sin interfaz de internet, mandando por RF que está en la uart un mensaje mqtt. Si en el programa indico que el servidor se encuentra en el portatil, no sabrá por donde mandar los mensajes. Por eso lo de intentar crear como un broker local que haga de puente a la uart y así llegar al broker principal que se localice en el portátil. No sé si me explico :s

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109861/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-pedro-moronta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución para hacer funcionar el script en C que se encuentra arriba pasa por corregir en el thread el write. Se está enviando un buffer de 4096 valores pero realmente no está todo ocupado, entonces quedaría como:

```
    valread = recv( new_socket, buffer, 1024,0);
    if ( valread == -1 ) {
        printf ( "An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
        return 0 ;
    }        
    write(fd,buffer,valread);
```

Corrigiendo esto ya se pueden mandar datos por la UART. Luego quedaría el thread de recibirlos, pero que es realizar el mismo proceso.

¡Espero que sirva a alguien esto!